# Create drawable from Google map marker BitmapDescriptorFactory

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I'm using this code as default map markers for my google maps which is working fine.

`BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);`

What I want to do now is set that map marker to an `ImageView` so it acts as a kind of bullet point if a user wants to view map data in a list. My problem is that I can't seem to find a method that will assign an `BitmapDescriptor`  variable to an `ImageView`

`BitmapDescriptor filterIcon = null;
 filterIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
 imageView.setBackground(filterIcon);`

That's my current code but of course is throwing an error.